# Why is my Android WebView app showing a white screen after the splash screen?

Tags: kotlin, android-webview, android-splashscreen

Hiiii
I'm a new developer for android and just started itself. I am developing an app for a school competition.
It is a web view app with a splash screen.
I have set up the splash screen and have set up the web view as well.
however whenever T open the app, its just a white blank screen after the splash screen.:(
I have tried all possible solutions.
Please do help:(

The second after the splash screen, instead of the web view its just a black white screen.

I expected the web view to appear and come as per my lessons and tutorials, however it didn't.
I am using android studio with kotlin to develop the app.

Comment: This is kind of a broad question, you'll need to post some code like your main Activity, how you're setting up the WebView and displaying something in it, and your Activity's layout file. Otherwise people can only guess at what's happening. One thing you can try is opening the Layout Inspector in Android Studio when you run your app - it'll show you exactly what's displaying on the screen, where your WebView is etc, and that will help you see if your layout is broken and you're just looking at the Activity's background (which would look like a white screen by default)

Comment: @cactustictacs val mWebView = findViewById<View>(R.id.Try1) as WebView
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://breezometer.com/air-quality-map/air-quality")

        val webSettings = mWebView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true // Enable DOM storage

mWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

mWebView.canGoBack()
mWebView.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
&& event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
&& mWebView.canGoBack()
) {
mWebView.goBack()
return@OnKeyListener true

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Don't paste code in comments, it's unreadable! Edit your question and paste it into a code block so it's formatted correctly. And like I said, we need to see your Activity code to have any idea of what you're doing when that Activity starts. Have you checked your logs to see if there are any error messages? Have you tried adding `https://`  at the front of your URL? Are you doing everything in this guide, including adding the `INTERNET` permission? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview